# Local inverse function Theorem from $R \to R$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find a reference for a local inverse function theorem for $f: R \to R$. After some online search, I hope I can find some reference close to the link below but I couldn't find out the original reference: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/131-inverse-functions-via-interpolation-local-inverse-function-theorem-asserts-f-c-functio-q86626586

I thought this might be in a standard reference and somebody can kindly refer to me. Many thanks.

Comment: Surely this would suffice? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement

Comment: I was aware of the link but it is not clear to me which one of the cited references is for my specific inquiry.